# Calling another function through eval by passing arguments in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, eval

I have written the following code for passing arguments to eval function in sample.py and calling the function in another module

Login_CSA.py . I am getting error like "Main() takes exactly 4 arguments (0 given)"

### sample.py:

```
def calling():

    str='Login_CSA'

    eval(str , 10 , 20, 30 , 40)

calling()
```

### Login_CSA.py:

```
def Main(a,b,c,d):

   z=a+b+c+d
   print z

Main()
```

can u guys show me a solution for this how to call a function through eval by passing arguments

Answer (score 2):

Your `Login_CSA.py` is broken per se. As soon as you import it,

```
def Main(a,b,c,d):

   z=a+b+c+d
   print z

Main()
```

you get an error because the `Main()` call won't work as `Main()` expects exactly 4 arguments.

If you **have removed this `Main()` call**, you will be able to import the module as wanted, e. g. with Martijn's solution which he, alas, deleted:

```
import importlib

mod = importlib.import_module('Login_CSA')
mod.Main(10, 20, 30, 40)
```

Now the import process should succeed, and you should have access to the module's `Main()` function. (But please rename it the right way - titlecase names are reserved for classes.)

Comment: @somesh Well, what is this alone `Main()` call supposed to do? What if you just omit it? In this case, Martijn's deleted answer should perfectly work.

Comment: @glglgl my scenario is similar to that example so i just posted a small example

Comment: @somesh And you keep the same error despite the removal of the `Main()` call from `Login_CSA.py`?

Comment: @glglgl i have removed the Main() and after passed like eval(str, 10, 20) , now getting error message as "locals must be a mapping"

Comment: @somesh Please edit your question appropriately, and provide the **full** traceback.

Comment: @somesh Oh, by any chance, you don't still use `eval`? Do it the `importlib` way.